# Setting up a server accessible over LAN

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, archive, apt

I am trying to set up a server (Ubuntu 14.04), which is not connected to the internet, just accessible over LAN.

**Can't replace the image of the server being used.**

I am using Ubuntu system as my local machine and I want to transfer all the packages installed in the current system to the server.

I tried installing packages like build-tools-essential, node.js using deb files over ssh, but the process gets stuck when it comes to dependencies. I also tried manually installing the dependencies manually, but there's heck lot of them.

Any suggestions, how to package all the installed packages in my current system - which I can transfer at once to the server.

Comment: You could try installing as much as possible from the installation DVD. You can also find downloaded packages on your other machine at `/var/cache/apt/archives` (until you clean them with `apt-get clean`).

Comment: what about the other packages like Node.js, Java and other stuffs?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.